# Python urllib2 request before response

Tags: python

I am trying to write a fast crawler in python, but I don't want to do it with thread. 
I read some article that Scrapy is single thread and could make request before response return. 
I wonder if there is any example code to do the same with urllib or urllib2 and make new request before reponse returns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Scrapy is open source, why not take a look? That said, I'm pretty sure it is threaded as it uses twisted, which utilises threading heavily.

Comment: Yes, I agree, Scrapy is great, It has lots of build in features like request and reponse. I am just trying to find out how to break into request and reponse, like 5 requests, don't wait for 1st response return to send out 2nd request.

Comment: You have already answered that - threads.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy is fine, but if you are looking for alternatives, have a look at [Eventlet](http://eventlet.net/). It's based on `greenthreads` (aka coroutines). They even have a simple web-crawler example - http://eventlet.net/#web-crawler-example

Comment: Thank you, spinlok, I will have a look on Eventlet.